# React app: Jest encountered an unexpected token webpack typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, jestjs, ts-jest

I created react app using create-react-app command.For reducing build size i ejected react app. After that i added build related configuration inside webpack.config.js. Earlier testcases are running fine. But now test cases are throwing error like unexpected token.

package.json:

```json
     "scripts": {
        "analyze": "source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'",
        "start": "node scripts/start.js",
        "build": "node scripts/build.js",
        "test": "node scripts/test.js",
        "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.+(js|jsx|json|css|md|ts|tsx|scss)\"",
        "lint": "eslint .",
        "lint:fix": "eslint --fix ."
      },
    "jest": {
        "roots": [
          "<rootDir>/src"
        ],
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
          "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
          "!src/**/*.d.ts"
        ],
        "setupFiles": [
          "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
        ],
        "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
          "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts"
        ],
        "testMatch": [
          "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
          "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
        ],
        "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
        "transform": {
          "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
          "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
          "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js",
          "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest",
          "^.+\\.jsx|js?$": "babel-jest"
        },
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
          "/node_modules/(?!@babel).+\\.js$"
        ],
        "modulePaths": [],
        "moduleNameMapper": {
          "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
          "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
        },
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
          "web.js",
          "js",
          "web.ts",
          "ts",
          "web.tsx",
          "tsx",
          "json",
          "web.jsx",
          "jsx",
          "node"
        ],
        "watchPlugins": [
          "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
          "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
        ]
      },
      "babel": {
        "presets": [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          "@babel/preset-react"
        ]
      }
    }
```

```
Error:
Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token
  Details:

    SyntaxError: /Users/syam/APP_NEW/src/redux/models/ItemInfo.ts: Unexpected token (4:6)

      2 | 
      3 | class ItemInfo {
    > 4 |   name: string;
        |       ^
      5 |   age: string;
      6 |   id: string;
      7 |   city: string;

      at Object._raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/location.js:233:45)
      at Object.raiseWithData (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/location.js:228:17)
      at Object.raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/location.js:212:17)
      at Object.unexpected (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/util.js:151:16)
      at Object.parseClassMemberWithIsStatic (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:1442:12)
      at Object.parseClassMember (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:1266:10)
      at callback (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:1199:14)
      at Object.withTopicForbiddingContext (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:2386:14)
      at Object.parseClassBody (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:1176:10)
      at Object.parseClass (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:1136:22)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following along with [the Jest guide for integrating with TypeScript](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-typescript) and [the basic-usage section in the ts-jest documentation](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/presets/#basic-usage). I don't have experience with jest or ts-jest, but from a quick glance, your package.json configuration doesn't seem to follow either of those documented setups.

As stated by the original asker in the comments, if they run test cases with create-app config, everything works, but when they eject webpack, things don't work. They need webpack-related settings.